# How to retrieve an image from mysql database

Tags: php, mysqli

I encrypted an image and stored in the database but while retrieving it it's not working certain values are displaying in the browser.

```
if($_POST())
{
if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
if($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0) {
// Connect to the database
$dbLink = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'resume');
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
}
$name = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
$mime = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['type']);
$data = $dbLink->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES  ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));
}
}
INSERT INTO `upload` (
`name`, `title`, `data`, `emailid`
)
VALUES (
'{$name}', '{$mime}', '{$data}','$valid_emailid'
)";

}
<form method="post"  name="myform" onsubmit="return validateform()" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file" id="upload" />

<form method="post"  name="myform"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file" id="upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: Could you provide some code? How you encrypted it and tried to retrieve and display it?

Comment: could you add more details - codes; sample output; etc?

Comment: You could use a separate file to get the images and pass an ID into it. So your HTML would look like this:

    <img src="image.php?imageid=1" />

Then with image.php, you could select it from the database and echo the image out to the PHP page. However, you must use image headers to ensure that an image is displayed:

    header('Content-Length: '.strlen($image_data));
    header("Content-type: image/png");

Comment: no i didnt decrypt it..i dont know how to do it..i encrypted in form tag...i will provide the code shortly

Comment: this is how i inserted and retrieved as usual

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't encrypt an image.
2. Don't store it in database.
3. Don't have a single problem with getting it back.

As simple as that.

If you have some problem at hand, which made you think you need an image stored in database - ask a question on this very main problem. And be told of the proper solution.